# How to shmat a char var[][], C

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to atach a `char shm[][]` var into shared memory and i have the following piece of code.

```
int main(){
    int shmid;
    key_t key;
    char shm[15][10];

    if ((key = ftok("test.c", 'R')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    shmid=shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(shmid<0){
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }


    shm=shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if(shm==(void*)-1){ 
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Trying to compile i am getting the following compilation error:

```
error: assignment to expression with array type
     shm=shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't assign a new address to an array... you'd need to use a pointer instead for that (like `char (*shm)[10]`).

Comment: An array is not  pointer!

Comment: You are trying to assign a pointer to an array, which is not allowed. You could try declaring `shm` as a pointer to type `char [10]` as follows: `char (*shm)[10];`. You can index `shm[x][y]` like an array (although it is not an array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
char (*shm)[10] = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
```

This is a pointer to a two-dimensional rectangular array with an unknown number of rows and ten columns.

Answer (score 0):

`char *shm[15][10]` is an array type but `void *shmat(int shmid, const void *shmaddr,
int shmflg);` returns the pointer to the memory.

What you should probably do is:

1. Change `char shm[15][10];` to `char *shm;` so now it is a pointer to the memory location containing an array of chars.
2. Add a cast from the `(void *)` to `(char *)`

`shm = (char *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);`

[shmat(2) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat)

Comment: He had a 2D array of `char`, not a 2D array of `char *`.  Also, why change to a `char *` instead of a `char (*)[10]`? (with the latter he'd be able to index it the same way as the array he had... a plain `char *` would complicate things).